# Disabling ECDSA

Tags: windows, ssh, arch-linux, openssh

Guys I've just installed ArchLinux on my Cubieboard, but I can't connect via ssh to the target. Problem is in encryption. Putty and a SSH client on my Android device doesn't support the algorithm. So I need to **disable** the ECDSA encryption. How Can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Instead, figure out what the actual problem is. Perhaps share the error messages PuTTY gives you, instead of forcing us to guess.

The problem with your question right now is, PuTTY actually has no issues at all with connecting to servers that use ECDSA. (Which is a rather large part of the world's SSH servers.) It has no issues with them because ECDSA is just one of many algorithms they offer, and it's enough for the client and server to share at least *one* algorithm that both sides support.

And the default offer sent by OpenSSH (which neither ArchLinux nor ArchLinux-ARM have changed) is fairly large; among algorithms supported by PuTTY it includes both RSA and DSA for authentication.

So PuTTY cannot fail the connection unless you reconfigured the server to offer *only* ECDSA. And if that's the case, disabling ECDSA would leave you with no algorithms at all; instead, you need to *enable* something else (like RSA).

Open your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and look for any of these settings:

- `Ciphers`
- `HostKey`
- `KexAlgorithms`

If you find any, remove (or comment out), then restart sshd.